# Call a function after onload event

Tags: javascript, events, onload

I have the following problem which I don't know how to solve.

There are two select elements on the page. On the first one options are static and the second have a dynamic elements which are changed based on selection in the first one. On onload event function is called that is filling options in the second select elements.

Values from select element are inside form and these values need to be saved after form submit (page will be refreshed) so the selected options can be preserved. I'm saving previous values in $_POST variable and setting options with function that is called on form submit.

Problem is that the function for selecting options is called before onload event. Function called on onload event overwrites selected option and the first option is always selected.

Any idea how to solve this?

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>    
    <meta charset = "utf-8">
    <link href="style/styleFTT.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"> 

    <script type="text/javascript">
        //php code: echo "var operatorPositions = $jsonOperatorPositions; \n";


        function updateOperatorPositions(){
            lineId = document.getElementById("line");
            selectedValue = lineId[lineId.selectedIndex].text;
            var operatorPositionSelect = document.getElementById("operatorPositions");

            operatorPositionSelect.options.length = 0; //emprty previous options from selection

            // fill the selection with new options
            var j = 0;        
            for (var i = 1; i<operatorPositions.length; i++){
                if (operatorPositions[i]["line"] == selectedValue) {
                    operatorPositionSelect.options[j] = new Option(operatorPositions[i]["positionOfOperator"], operatorPositions[i]["positionOfOperator"]);
                    j += 1;
                }
            }
            console.log('Refreshed field in the SECOND select element');
        }    

        function showMenu(elmnt) {
            document.getElementById(elmnt).style.display="block";
        }
        function hideMenu(elmnt) {
            document.getElementById(elmnt).style.display="none";
        } 

        function setSelectOption(ElementID, Value){
            console.log('Setting the new option. '+'ElementID: '+ElementID+ " Value: "+Value);
            document.getElementById(ElementID).value = Value; 
        }
    </script>


</head>


<body onload="updateOperatorPositions()">
<div class="wrap">
    <?php include'includes/header.php'?> 
    <div class="main">
        <form method="post" >  

            <!-- --------------------------  TABLE FOR SELECTING POSITION ---------------------------------->    
            <h5>1. Step</h5>
            <table id="selectPosition">
                <tr>
                    <th>Select line</th>
                    <th>Select operators position</th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>             
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <select name="lineTitle" id="line" onchange="updateOperatorPositions()">
                            <option value="UP15" selected >UP15</option>
                            <option value="UP15 Rotor">UP15 Rotor</option>
                            <option value="UP15 Stator line 3">UP15 Stator line 3</option>
                            <option value="UP26">UP26</option>
                            <option value="UP26 Rotor">UP26 Rotor</option>
                            <option value="UP26 Stator">UP26 Stator</option>
                            <option value="Niro" >Niro</option>
                            <option value="Sololift">Sololift</option>
                            <option value="Composit">Composit</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <select name="opPos" id="operatorPositions" >
                               // filled with javascript function
                        </select>                    
                    </td>
                    <td ><input type="submit" name="submitPosition" value="Select" style="width:10em;"> </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <!-- ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->

            <!-- --------------------------  TABLE FOR REMOVING ERROR ----------------------------------->
            <h5 id="title2b" style="display:none;">2.b Step (in case that you want to delete exsiting one)</h5>
            <table id="ErrorList" style="display:none">

                    // This is called on submit button    
                    <script> 
                            showMenu("ErrorDetails"); showMenu("ErrorList"); showMenu("title2b"); showMenu("title2a"); 
                            setSelectOption("line", <?php echo $LINE; ?>);
                            setSelectOption("operatorPositions", <?php echo $OP_POS; ?>);                            
                    </script>

            </table>
        </form>
   </div>
</div>
</body>




</html>
```

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: Can you post a jsfiddle of your current code? Something we can look at? Are you using a JS framework, like jQuery?

Comment: Please post the related HTML and JS only, the PHP code just takes space from your problem. If it creates HTML/JS we need to know, add it to the question as HTML.

Comment: Why you don't use php to set selected element? just echo `selected` attribute (`selected="selected"`) when element is selected.

Comment: where do you think that I should put that?

Comment: just guessing, but maybe onchange can help in this case?

Comment: But there are some php lines that are important for the whole process. don't you agree?

Comment: Ok I'll do that but I think I'll make a mess.

Comment: You can narrow it down, we don't need to see all the options in selects, omit the table, just show the relevant code...

Comment: It should be ok now. I added some additional comments that should substitute php sode

Comment: Yep, looks much better now : ). Why don't you just put the code from inline script to a function, and call it at the end of `updateOperatorPositions()`? Hmm... I'm sorry, you seem to get more stupid suggestions ; ).

Comment: I've tried that but when the page is loaded for the first time variable $_POST is not defined.. But maybe if I put `if (isset($_POST)){}` could solve this

Comment: It's working now. Thank you for the help! :) Would you like to copy this comment as an answer so I could set it as official?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd put the code from inline script to a function, and call it at the end of `updateOperatorPositions()`. If there's some variable(s), which is not defined at the first invoke, you can put the function call in an `if(){}`, and check everything needed is available.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
window.onload = function() { 
   // page loaded
};
```

Or in jQuery

```
$(window).load(function(){
    // page loaded
});
```

Or as an inline event on the body element

```
<body onload="runOnloadFn();">
```

Comment: I already have that in my code.. but timeline is not good. Function for adjusting selected option needs to be executed after function called on onload event.

Comment: @justRadojko Try the triggering the onchange event on the first select.

Comment: No luck with that neither